# htaccess FilterProvider giving error 500

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using `Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) PHP/5.5.3 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3`, and i get an Error 500 when i try opening this page in my browser
**/xamppfiles/htdocs/wm/frontend/www/** Below if my error log.

```
[Tue Mar 18 17:03:51.923726 2014] [core:alert] [pid 933] [client ::1:51765] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wm/frontend/www/.htaccess: FilterProvider takes three arguments, filter-name provider-name match-expression
```

here is my htaccess file

```
   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
<IfModule filter_module>
  FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
  FilterChain     COMPRESS
  FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_filter.c>
  # Legacy versions of Apache
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

i tried this, but no luck either

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4.4>
<IfModule filter_module>
  FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
  FilterChain     COMPRESS
  FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</IfVersion>

<IfVersion <= 2.4.4>
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/html'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/css'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/plain'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/x-component'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/javascript'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/json'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xhtml+xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/rss+xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/atom+xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/svg+xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/x-icon'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/x-font-ttf'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'font/opentype'"
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</IfVersion>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your  logic is flawed. You have the %{Content_Type} syntax being used for the older version, and both IfVersion conditionals will match version 2.4.4 because you have "or equal to" on both conditionals.

This should work:

```
<IfVersion < 2.4.4>
<IfModule filter_module>
FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
FilterChain     COMPRESS
FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</IfVersion>

<IfVersion >= 2.4.4>
<IfModule filter_module>
FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/html'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/css'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/plain'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/x-component'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/javascript'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/json'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xhtml+xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/rss+xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/atom+xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/svg+xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/x-icon'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/x-font-ttf'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'font/opentype'"
FilterChain     COMPRESS
FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</IfVersion>
```

Comment: Actually you could make this even nicer by putting the `<IfModule filter_module>` tags around everything else (saves 2 lines) and also use an additional `<IfModule version.c>` check around the `<IfVersion>`-blocks to make sure IfVersion is even possible (otherwise it would result in another error).

Comment: You saved my day...! Thanks