# .htaccess: FilterProvider issue

Tags: javascript, json, .htaccess

this is probably really simple, but my coder is on holiday and out of comms and I'm a graphic designer with fairly basic HTML and CSS knowledge. This is beyond me.

One of our client sites is getting this issue:

> .htaccess: FilterProvider takes three arguments, filter-name
>   provider-name match-expression

I think it relates to this section of the .htaccess file, but I'm damned if I know what the answer is:

> # Force deflate for mangled headers
>   developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
>   
>       
>         SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$
>   ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
>         RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
>          
>   
>     # HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:   
>       FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/x-icon
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
>       FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
>       FilterChain     COMPRESS
>       FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no   
>   
>     
>       # Legacy versions of Apache
>       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
>       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
>       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
>       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
>       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype

---

If anyone can help out, I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: if you could post the .htaccess file with line breaks in place, that would make it extremely easier to help

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475131/htaccess-filterprovider-giving-error-500 ?

Comment: Formatting sorted. Thanks for that Link, Jaromanda X, but I'll be honest, I have no idea what that means :(

Comment: AHA! Pasted in that new code and it all works now!

Answer (score 9):

replace

```
FilterDeclare COMPRESS
...
...
...
FilterChain COMPRESS
FilterProtocol COMPRESS DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
```

with

```
FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/html'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/css'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/plain'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/x-component'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/javascript'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/json'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xhtml+xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/rss+xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/atom+xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/svg+xml'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/x-icon'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/x-font-ttf'"
FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'font/opentype'"
FilterChain     COMPRESS
FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
```

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, and this worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: future readers - I experienced this error while moving a site from apache 2.2 to apache 2.4 and this format change did the trick. If your curious. Here's why: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_filter.html#upgrade